# POSIX error 12 ("Cannot allocate memory") while uploading files from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, ios, put

I'm working on an iPhone application that involves uploading full photos from the camera (generally between 1.5 to 2.0 MB each) as well as their thumbnails (much smaller) to Amazon S3.

The thumbnails always successfully upload, but *sometimes* the full images don't, and when they fail, they fail with POSIX error code 12, aka ENOMEM. However, I've added debug code to print the amount of free memory when the error happens, and there's always quite a bit free, usually more than 100 MB.

Furthermore, the error crops up more often when the upload is happening over 3G and less when it's over wifi -- which seems strange, since the request isn't downloading much and the file being uploaded is already in memory (I've also tried streaming it from disk with no improvement).

I've tried uploading the file using NSURLConnection, the Foundation CFHTTP* functions, and the ASIHTTPRequest library, but regardless, the error happens with the same frequency. Even stranger, all my Googling has revealed is that end users sometimes get error code 12 from Safari -- I haven't seen any iOS developers mentioning it. I'm working with an inherited code base, so it's possible there's something wrong with it, but I'm not even sure what to look for. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what call is returning ENOMEM?

Comment: When I was using NSURLConnection, I'd get the error as part of the didFailWithError delegate method -- an NSError with the POSIX error domain, error code 12, and the localized description "Cannot allocate memory". When I used a CFHTTPMessageRef, it would fail when calling CFReadStreamRead() (function returned -1), and afterward errno would be equal to 12.

Comment: I see the same issue while trying to upload files with Google Docs API  on 3G. A post on Dropbox API mentions similar issue: http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=25351. It seems to happen on slow connections (3G) with large files.

Comment: It seems to be a bug that has to be reported to Apple.

Comment: Yeah, it may be a legitimate bug. I'll look into reporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I was able to work around this issue, is using sockets directly and forming HTTP header manually. So my uploading code currently looks like this:

```
- (void)socketClose
{
    [_inputStream setDelegate:nil];
    [_inputStream close];
    [_inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    SCR_RELEASE_SAFELY(_inputStream);

    [_outputStream setDelegate:nil];
    [_outputStream close];
    [_outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    SCR_RELEASE_SAFELY(_outputStream);

    SCR_RELEASE_SAFELY(_headerBuffer);
}

- (void)sendRequest
{
    [self socketClose];
    SCR_RELEASE_SAFELY(_headerBuffer);

    if (!_shouldCancel)
    {
        NSString *httpMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"POST upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                 "Host:"
#ifndef TESTBED
                                 " %@"
#endif
                                 "\r\n"
                                 "User-Agent: MyApp/3.0.0 CFNetwork/534 Darwin/10.7.0\r\n"
                                 "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
                                 "Accept: */*\r\n"
                                 "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n"
                                 "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
                                 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                                 "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n"
                                 "data="
#ifndef TESTBED
                                 , [self.serverUrl host]
#endif
                                 , _bytesToUpload];

        NSString *key = @"data=";
        NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        _bytesToUpload -= [keyData length];
        _bytesToUpload = MAX(0, _bytesToUpload);

        _headerBuffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[httpMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        _writtenDataBytes = 0;

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault
                                           , (CFStringRef)[self.serverUrl host]
#ifdef TESTBED
                                           , 8888
#else
                                           , 80
#endif
                                           , (CFReadStreamRef *)(&_inputStream)
                                           , (CFWriteStreamRef *)(&_outputStream));

        [_inputStream setDelegate:self];
        [_outputStream setDelegate:self];

        [_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [_inputStream open];
        [_outputStream open];
    }
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    if (_outputStream == theStream)
    {
        switch (streamEvent)
        {
            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            {
                [self regenerateTimeoutTimer];
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);
                NSInteger length = _headerBuffer.length;

                if (length > 0)
                {
                    NSInteger written = [_outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[_headerBuffer bytes] maxLength:length];
                    NSInteger rest = length - written;

                    if (rest > 0)
                    {
                        memmove([_headerBuffer mutableBytes], (const uint8_t *)[_headerBuffer mutableBytes] + written, rest);
                    }

                    [_headerBuffer setLength:rest];
                }
                else
                {
                    const uint8_t *dataBytes = [_data bytes];

                    while ([_outputStream hasSpaceAvailable] && (_writtenDataBytes < _bytesToUpload))
                    {
                        NSInteger written = [_outputStream write:dataBytes
                                                       maxLength:MIN(_dataLength, _bytesToUpload - _writtenDataBytes)];

                        if (written > 0)
                        {
                            _writtenDataBytes += written;
                        }
                    }
                }

                [self regenerateTimeoutTimer];

                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);
                [self reportError:[theStream streamError]];                
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);
                [self socketClose];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (_inputStream == theStream)
    {
        switch (streamEvent)
        {
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);

                /* Read server response here if you wish */

                [self socketClose];

                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);
                [self reportError:[theStream streamError]];
                break;
            }
            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            {
                SCR_RELEASE_TIMER(_timeoutTimer);
                [self socketClose];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although ASIHTTPRequest could work here, we decided to walk away from such dependencies both in order to get performance and to keep everything under our own control accurately. You can use Wireshark tool in order to debug this kind of things.

Comment: What does your regenerateTimeoutTimer do? Call [self stream:theStream handleEvent:streamEvent] and do before that... ?

Comment: regenerateTimeoutTimer simply resets the timer that I use to determine when the request timed out. The sense here is if we got even some bytes, we are starting to wait again. But if we don't receive any more bytes in the specified amount of time (as long as you wish - configurable), our class generates a custom timed-out exception and thus we don't wait forever (sometimes it happens on network errors so take as a workaround).

Comment: After some more time working on this and seeing `Cannot allocate memory' error, I came to the fact, that under some circumstances it may appear even in the sample code above. The key thing is to open the socket correctly. It's shown here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245

Answer (score 1):

The key to getting around this issue is to upload the file using a stream. When using NSMutableURLRequest, this can be accomplished using something similar to the following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBodyStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath]];
```

When using ASIHTTPRequest, streaming a file is accomplished with this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest* request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostBodyFilePath:filePath];
rRequest.shouldStreamPostDataFromDisk = YES;
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the request method to POST or PUT.

Comment: I actually tried this. It seems like the way to go with large file uploads in any case, and it may have decreased the frequency of ENOMEM errors, but they still happen. Still, thanks for pointing that out, it's a good technique.

Answer (score 1):

Have resolved this error with using operation for request (`NSMutableUrlConnection`) with `@autorelease{}` for main function.
NSPOXIS appears only sometimes.

```
- (void)main
 NSURLConnection* connection;
    @autoreleasepool //urgently needed for 3G upload
    {

        self.currentRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.php"]];
        [self.currentRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

        [self.currentRequest setHTTPBody:self.data];//inpustStream doesn't work

        connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:self.currentRequest delegate:self];
        [connection start];

    }//end autorelease pool

        do 
        {

            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate distantFuture]];
            if ([self isCancelled])
            {
                connection          = nil;
                isFailed = YES;
                break;
            }
            self.status(statusUpdateMessage);
        } 
        while (!isFailed && !isCompleted);
        [timer invalidate];//test
        timer = nil;

//corresponding of status via blocks
        self.completed(!isFailed);
        self.status(isFailed ? errorMessage : @"Completed");
        if (isFailed)
        {
            self.failed(errorMessage != nil ? errorMessage : @"Undefined error");
        }

        self.data = nil;
        self.currentRequest = nil;

        connection = nil;

}
```